# RGBA(0.500, 0.500, 0.500, 1.000) returns RGBA(0.502, 0.502, 0.502, 1.000) when raycast color sampling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors, lighting

I have a white plane, the material is #FFFFFF, pure white. when I raycast it, it returns a value of RGBA(0.804, 0.804, 0.804, 0.804) and not RGBA(1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000) which is what I expect.

At first, I thought this was a lighting problem, and it still may be. I have tried everything I can think of with changing the lighting. Global Illumination, intensity on the directional light I have in the scene, I've even changed the plane to an unlit texture.

This is the code that gets the plane ready to change pixels on `tex2dGrid = new Texture2D(10, 10, TextureFormat.ARGB32, true);`

and this is how I am sampling the color of the pixels

```
if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.down), out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
{
    Texture2D tex2d = (Texture2D)hit.transform.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture;
    // get the pixel coords
    var pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;
    // convert to hitpoint coordins to texture coordins
    pixelUV.x *= tex2d.width;
    pixelUV.y *= tex2d.height;
    // get the color of the pixel
    Color colPixel = tex2d.GetPixel((int)pixelUV.x, (int)pixelUV.y);
}
```

```
colPixel is returning RGBA(1.000, 1.000, 1.000, 1.000) for white
colPixel is returning RGBA(0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000) for black
RGBA(0.750, 0.750, 0.750, 1.000) is RGBA(0.749, 0.749, 0.749, 1.000)
RGBA(0.500, 0.500, 0.500, 1.000) is RGBA(0.502, 0.502, 0.502, 1.000)
RGBA(0.250, 0.250, 0.250, 1.000) is RGBA(0.251, 0.251, 0.251, 1.000)
```

I think it works for black because maybe my lighting is on the darker side?

I need to be able to sample the pixels with complete accuracy and the plane should be returning complete white.

Comment: Its called "floating point error." How well can you represent one half of 255 as an integer?

Comment: @Draco18s hmm, yeah could be I suppose, maybe I need another method.

Comment: Turns out instead of using 0.000-1.000 there are no issues with 0-255 (color32) but now when I change the color of the plane object the sampled color is always 205,205,205,205, I don't understand, my plane is green!

Comment: Edit your question with the new code

Comment: @Draco18s well I just found another workaround so this is a non-issue now.

Comment: @RvBVakama then what is? If you "fixed" your problem yourself please either remove the question or preferably add a proper answer to it so people with the same issue can use your solution.

Comment: @derHugo oh sorry, I was worried to remove it because I've been question banned in the past for removing. In fact for some reason I've been banned from asking questions even for asking this question. I guess it's because it hasn't had any votes yet. I also don't have the solution so I can't post any answer.

Comment: as said the prefered and proper way to go would be to provide a proper answer to the question even it is yourself who answers it. And yes if you repeatedly delete your questions it seems that you could have figured it out on your own without posting a question here at all ;)

Comment: @derHugo rubber duck programming often is the case with stackoverflow, and in the past I have been penalized for it. The problem is that you can't forsee it and thus I don't know what to do now since I don't have an applicable answer. My answer only suits my project and doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: If it fixes your specifc question for your specific problem anyway an answer given by anyone else might only apply to your specific case. Therefore there is nothing speaking against you adding your found solution as an answer. There might still someone come back in the future with a better general solution for your problem. To me it sounded like simply using Color32 and checking e.g. for `(128,128,128)` should solve it, right?

Comment: @derHugo yes that was half of the solution that I used the other half which is the main issue is that I could not figure out how to not sample the 0.804 value from the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Use color32 instead of just color. `Color32 colPixel = tex2d.GetPixel((int)pixelUV.x, (int)pixelUV.y); }` This way you won't be using floating point and will only be using integers, thus there will not be any floating point inaccuracy. I'm not sure about the plane, sorry.